# PHP reading submitted form and placing results in array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form with dynamically created input fields - upon submitting it I would like to place all the generated data into an array using php.

An example of the html:-

```
<fieldset id="usp">
<input type="text" id="usp_1" name="usp_1" />
<input type="text" id="usp_2" name="usp_2" />
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" id="uspTot" name="uspTot" />
```

input id=usp_1 and usp_2 were generated by Jquery on the fly - there can be any number of these inputs depending on the user so Jquery keeps a tally in the hidden field id=uspTot

When the form is posted I have tried to put the values of these input elements into a simple array using the following PHP code :-

```
$uspCount = $_POST["uspTot"];
for ($i=1; $i<=$uspCount; $i++)
 {
  $uspString[$i] = $_POST["usp_" + $i];
 };
```

It doesn't work of course! But I can't see why not?

Any pointers?

EDIT: this is the error code I receive:-

> Notice: Undefined variable: POST in C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Websites\example\html\submitbrief.php on line 21

EDIT 2:

This is the var_dump as requested by @Michael:-

```
array(36) { ["co_name"]=> string(11) "Daves autos" ["co_about"]=> string(16) "established 1969" ["co_id"]=> string(10) "Dave Smith" ["co_email"]=> string(21) "dave@davesautos.co.uk" ["co_phone"]=> string(11) "34435454545" ["usp_1"]=> string(9) "its great" ["usp_2"]=> string(9) "i love it" ["usp_3"]=> string(15) "its about car4s" ["uspTot"]=> string(1) "3" ["co_keyw_1"]=> string(0) "" ["co_keyw_2"]=> string(0) "" ["co_keyw_3"]=> string(0) "" ["co_keyw_4"]=> string(0) "" ["co_keyw_5"]=> string(0) "" ["co_compet"]=> string(0) "" ["ex_pos"]=> string(0) "" ["ex_neg"]=> string(0) "" ["ex_url"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_basic"]=> string(3) "yes" ["pac_cms"]=> string(2) "no" ["pac_eco"]=> string(2) "no" ["pac_ax"]=> string(4) "base" ["pac_ie6"]=> string(2) "no" ["pac_url"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_dom"]=> string(2) "no" ["pac_ins_1_url"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_ins_1_det"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_keyw_1"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_keyw_2"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_keyw_3"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_keyw_4"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_keyw_5"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_name"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_dem"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_gui"]=> string(0) "" ["pac_tex"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Did you check that your jQuery code is indeed updating uspTot and that all the post variables are indeed being posted?

Comment: Are you sure uspTot is counting properly and starting the count at 1 and not 0?

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?  Please post the entire form, also the output of `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: @Mat - Yes I did and it is :)

Comment: @Michael - How remiss of me :) Sorry Notice: Undefined variable: POST in C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Websites\example\html\submitbrief.php on line 21

Comment: And post line 21. Didn't you use $POST on that line (notice the missing underscore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your for loop:

```
$uspString[$i] = $_POST["usp_" . $i];
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not change your HTML markup so the values get posted as an array, and forget about the hidden tally or the other things?

Change your markup to the following:

```
<fieldset id="usp">
    <input type="text" id="usp_1" name="usp[1]" />
    <input type="text" id="usp_2" name="usp[2]" />
</fieldset>
```

Then, access the array of values with this:

```
$arrValues = $_POST['usp'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use  .  instead  +
$uspString[$i] = $*POST["usp*" **.** $i];

Comment: I'm afraid this gives me the same result, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes of course. Sorry didn't check parser output after sending answer.